# LuaLaTeX set a path in lua

Tags: macros, luatex, lua

I have defined a command

```
\newcommand{\mypath}{/Documents/Myfile/additionalresources/}
```

that contains the path to some external files that I need in my main file. I need to use the `\mypath` command to set some `dofile` in a Lua part of my document, and I've tried with

```
dofile('\luastringN{\mypath}'..'mydata.lua'),
```

but it didn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please could you be more clear for your question? What is your main file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume you use the `\luastringN` command from the `luacode` package.
What does `\luastringN` do? According to the [`luacode` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/luacode/luacode.pdf)

> Fortunately, LuaTEX offers a primitive that does exactly what we need: escape characters that need to be escaped in a Lua string. Unfortunately, it has a very long name (especially in the prefixed form available in LATEX): `\luatexluaescapestring`. Also, you need to think to use quotes in addition to this primitive. So this package provides a shorter version: `\luastring` **that also include the quotes**, so a safer version of `\foo` might be defined as
>   `\newcommand*\foo[2]{\luadirect{foo(\luastring{#1}, #2)}}`
>   It should be noted that the argument of `\luastring` is fully expanded before being turned into a Lua string.  In case where such an expansion is unwanted, two variants are provided: **`\luastringN`
>   for no expansion**, and `\luastringO` for one-level expansion (of the first token) only.

So `\luastringN` does not expand its argument and includes the quotes. This means

```
dofile('\luastringN{\mypath}'..'mydata.lua'),
```

becomes

```
dofile('"\\mypath "mydata.lua')
```

This fails because the file `"\mypath "mydata.lua` does not exists.

We have to change two things: We have to get rid of the additional quotes and expand `\mypath` to the actual path stored in `\mypath`.

Getting rid of the quotes is easy: *Never write quotes around `\luastringN`.*

For the expansion you have to decide between full expansion and one-level expansion.
Here there should be no difference because `\mypath` directly expands to the path and the path is not expandable, but I would recommend one-level expansion here: This avoids problems if you ever try to use a path containing active characters. So for one-level expansion, use `\luastringO`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newcommand{\mypath}{/Documents/Myfile/additionalresources/}
\begin{document}
\directlua{dofile(\luastringO{\mypath}..'mydata.lua')}
\end{document}
```

This works but there is another way to get the same result: Instead of using `\luastringO` to get the value of a macro from lua, just use the Lua function `token.get_macro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mypath}{/Documents/Myfile/additionalresources/}
\begin{document}
\directlua{dofile(token.get_macro'mypath' .. 'mydata.lua')}
\end{document}
```

This is more flexible because the macro name can be calculated by a Lua function, it is probably more efficient because the value of the macro is never inserted into the main token stream and you do not need any additional packages.

As more general advice I recommend to (almost) never use `\luastring[NO]` or `\luaescapestring`. The `token` library provides much nicer and safer interfaces for getting values from TeX.

One more detail: Instead of appending the strings with `..`, it is safer to use `file.join`: This ensures that there will always be a path separator between the components, even if `\mypath` does not have a trailing `/`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mypath}{/Documents/Myfile/additionalresources/}
\begin{document}
\directlua{dofile(file.join(token.get_macro'mypath', 'mydata.lua'))}
\end{document}
```