# Passing arguments from TeX to a Lua function

Tags: luatex

The following code is a simple example of passing arguments from TeX to Lua. Just passing the arguments directly (the version without `\luastringN`) gives an error.

```
(./luafunction.aux)./luafunction.lua:2: attempt to concatenate local 's' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ./luafunction.lua:2: in function 'joinstring'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\joinstring #1#2-> \directlua {joinstring(#1, #2)}

l.19 \joinstring{foo}{bar}
```

I noticed that other code used the macro `\luastringN` when passing arguments from TeX to Lua, so I did too. But this is completely Cargo Cult programming, because I have no idea why. The docunentation in the `luacode` manual isn't very enlightening. On section 1.2 on page 3 of the v1.2a manual where `\luastringN` is documented, it talks about escaping special characters. But there are no special characters in my example. And I don't understand what special handling is required to pass from TeX to Lua. Explanations appreciated - feel free to dumb it down.

Additionally, [this answer to the question "LuaLaTeX set a path in lua"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455129/3406) mentioned that one should use `token.get_macro` instead. The documentation on pg 10.6.4 of the `luatex` v 1.10 manual says:

> The get_macro function can be used to get the content of a macro

but I'm not sure what that means. Also, I did a search in TeX SE for `token.get_macro`, and got two hits.

So is that a better choice, and if so, why? And what does the `get_macro` function do, exactly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{luafunction2.lua}
function joinstring (s, t)
 tex.sprint(s .. t)
end

\end{filecontents*}
\directlua{require "luafunction2.lua"}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\joinstring[2]
{
  % \directlua{joinstring(#1, #2)}
  \directlua{joinstring(\luastringN{#1}, \luastringN{#2})}
}

\joinstring{foo}{bar}

\end{document}
```

Chat room discussion starts around [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50434105#50434105)

Comment: your example runs without error in texlive 2019

Comment: If all you are wondering about is how a TeX argument `#1` or whatever should be passed to Lua, you are overthinking things: is that the core question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The version without `\luastringN` gives the error. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @JosephWright That's one of my questions, yes. I ask several related ones here. Why is that "overthinking"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Well for example `get_macro` is in an _entirely_ different area

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, but that's about _getting the expansion of a TeX macro from Lua_, not _taking an explicit string from TeX_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94095/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-faheem-mitha).

Comment: I didn't follow the link to every referenced question, make the example here an example of whatever problem you want help with, currently the question is completely unclear

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "completely unclear" is a bit harsh.

Comment: @FaheemMitha an example that doesn't show the error is unclear. Beside this why is the commented part using substring and the other joinstring?

Comment: No, it is literally true, perhaps someone understands, but I have no idea what your question is. I tried the example and got no error and read your comment that said that the example was not an example, and now I have no idea what the issue is or what you want us to test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer They should both be joinstring, sorry. I've also changed the error message.

Comment: +1 for "But this is completely Cargo Cult programming, because I have no idea why."

Comment: See also: [Can the Lua part of LuaTeX know about tokens? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45293/can-the-lua-part-of-luatex-know-about-tokens?noredirect=1&lq=1) for possible options to preserve the catcode information.

Answer (score 7):

All that `\luastringN` does here is provide a wrapper for `\luaescapestring` plus a few wrinkles. I'd just write that out, at least for a 'practice' file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{luafunction2.lua}
function joinstring (s, t)
 tex.sprint(s .. t)
end
\end{filecontents*}
\directlua{require "luafunction2.lua"}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\joinstring[2]
{%
  \directlua{joinstring(
    "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}",
    "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}")
  }%
}

\joinstring{foo}{bar}

\end{document}
```

Notice that `\luaescapestring` carries out (`e`-type) expansion, so we need `\unexpanded` to avoid strange stuff happening. Also notice the `"` characters, which are needed to tell Lua we are passing a string. We don't have to worry about any `"` in the TeX input as `\luaescapestring` makes them safe.

Answer (score 6):

Since the Lua function `tex.sprint` expects to operate on strings (either string constants, variables of type `string`, or something that can be coerced into type `string` on the fly), defining the LaTeX-side macro as

```
\newcommand\joinstring[2]{\directlua{joinstring(#1,#2)}}
```

and then running

```
\joinstring{foo}{bar}
```

is incorrect, because `foo` and `bar` are not automatically converted into what Lua recognizes as strings. Indeed, the error message you reproduced shows that Lua considers `foo` and `bar` to be of type `nil`. Variables of type `nil` are definitely going to trip up the string concatenation operation `..` in the `tex.sprint ( s .. t )` instruction.

The two obvious remedies are

1. Place explicit quotation marks around the arguments of `\joinstring`, i.e., run

   ```
   \joinstring{"foo"}{"bar"}
   ```
2. define the LaTeX macro as

   ```
   \newcommand\joinstring[2]{\directlua{joinstring("#1","#2")}}
   ```

   I suppose that one could say that `\luastring{#1}` and especially `\luastringN{#1}` are elaborations (say, to prohibit expansion of `#1`) of the `"#1"` approach. They are also more robust in the sense that they can handle unbalanced (single and double) quote marks in their arguments; unbalanced double-quote marks is something that would trip up the `"#1"` approach.

---

A full MWE that implements the second idea -- notice that for the simple code at hand it's not necessary to load the `luacode` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{function joinstring (s,t) tex.sprint (s..t) end}
\newcommand\joinstring[2]{\directlua{joinstring("#1","#2")}}     
\begin{document}
\joinstring{foo}{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94099/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-mico).

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the `\luaescapestring` based solution in the other answers, you can also use the `token` library to pass arguments from TeX to Lua. This leads to minor speed improvements, because LuaTeX doesn't have to escape the string only for Lua to parse it again. So you might consider it especially when you expect long strings. Also this avoids mixing TeX and Lua code which can help if you later decide to use your code with `\luafunction` (or `\luadef`).

Anyway, you first have to decide if you want (`e`-type) expansion or not. The `token` functions always expand the arguments, so you have to apply `\unexpanded` if you do not want this. Then you can use `token.scan_argument` to read a argument that is given directly *after* the whole Lua code. If you decide to read an expanded argument, you can also handle the argument reading entirely through Lua, but then slightly different scanning rules apply. Especially in simple cases no braces are required around string arguments.

Here are some examples to see the actual effects of the different options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{luafunction2.lua}
function joinstring (s, t)
 tex.write(s, ', ' , t, ': ')
 tex.sprint(s .. t .. '.')
end
\end{filecontents*}
\directlua{require "luafunction2.lua"}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\joinstring[2]{
  \directlua{joinstring(token.scan_argument(), token.scan_argument())}%
  {\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}
}

\newcommand\expandedjoinstring[2]
{
  \directlua{joinstring(token.scan_argument(), token.scan_argument())}%
  {#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand\otherexpandedjoinstring
{
  \directlua{joinstring(token.scan_argument(), token.scan_argument())}%
}

\newcommand\foo{foo}
\newcommand\Bar{bar}
\verb|\joinstring{foo}{bar}|: \joinstring{foo}{bar}\\
\verb|\joinstring{\foo}{\Bar}|: \joinstring{\foo}{\Bar}\\
\verb|\joinstring foo bar|: \joinstring foo bar\\
\verb|\expandedjoinstring{foo}{bar}|: \expandedjoinstring{foo}{bar}\\
\verb|\expandedjoinstring{\foo}{\Bar}|: \expandedjoinstring{\foo}{\Bar}\\
\verb|\expandedjoinstring foo bar|: \expandedjoinstring foo bar\\
\verb|\otherexpandedjoinstring{foo}{bar}|: \otherexpandedjoinstring{foo}{bar}\\
\verb|\otherexpandedjoinstring{\foo}{\Bar}|: \otherexpandedjoinstring{\foo}{\Bar}\\
\verb|\otherexpandedjoinstring foo bar|: \otherexpandedjoinstring foo bar\\
\end{document}
```

[image]