# LuaLaTeX writing LaTeX commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, latex3, lua

I am trying to have LuaLatex automate some LaTex.

For example if I write :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,graphicx,tikz}

\usepackage[paperwidth=120pt, paperheight=120pt, margin=10pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, sharpish corners, opacityframe=0, opacityback=0, boxrule=0pt]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
            \draw[line width=0mm, white] (0,0) -- (100,0) -- (100,100) -- (0, 100);
            \draw[xshift=50, yshift=50] node[draw, anchor=north west]{AAA};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

my build works.

Now I would like to make Lua write this line :

```
            \draw[xshift=50, yshift=50] node[draw, anchor=north west]{AAA};
```

If I write :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,graphicx,tikz}
\directlua{dofile("placeTextNode.lua")}
\newcommand*{\textNode}{%
    \directlua{tex.write(textNode())}%
}

\usepackage[paperwidth=120pt, paperheight=120pt, margin=10pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, sharpish corners, opacityframe=0, opacityback=0, boxrule=0pt]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
            \draw[line width=0mm, white] (0,0) -- (100,0) -- (100,100) -- (0, 100);
            \textNode
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

and

```
function textNode()
    return "\draw[xshift=50, yshift=50] node[draw, anchor=north west]{AAA};"
end
```

I have an error message saying :

> invalid escape sequence near '"\d'

If I write :

```
function textNode()
    return "\\draw[xshift=50, yshift=50] node[draw, anchor=north west]{AAA};"
end
```

having added a \ in front of \draw, I don't have the error anymore, but the node does not appear.

Do you have an idea of what I should write in Lua ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest some change in your question title, something like LuaLaTeX automate LaTeX writing

Comment: You have to use `tex.sprint`.

Comment: Do you plan to do more complicated printings or not? Because your example doesn't really need LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the documentation, `tex.write` is intended "for use as a quick way to dump information". It intentionally adjusts catcodes to ensure that it's result does *not* get interpreted as special TeX commands. To pass TeX code, you need one of the `tex.print/sprint/tprint` functions instead. Since you want to print full lines with standard catcodes, `tex.print` is the most appropriate:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,graphicx,tikz}
\directlua{dofile("placeTextNode.lua")}
\newcommand*{\textNode}{%
    \directlua{tex.print(textNode())}%
}

\usepackage[paperwidth=120pt, paperheight=120pt, margin=10pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, sharpish corners, opacityframe=0, opacityback=0, boxrule=0pt]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
            \draw[line width=0mm, white] (0,0) -- (100,0) -- (100,100) -- (0, 100);
            \textNode
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but to me it says the following with print :
[\directlua]:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'textNode')
stack traceback:
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\textNode ->\directlua {tex.print(textNode())}
                                              
l.15             \textNode

Comment: @FilippoGuenzi That message means that there is no defined function `textNode`. Either you no longer load the file `placeTextNode.lua` or you changed the file to no longer define the function. If `placeTextNode.lua` exists and contains the second definition of `textNode` from your question (the one with `\\draw`) then the code from my answer will work

Comment: Thank you I didn't understand that I had to keep the \\draw version in the Lua file. It works now.

Comment: I was attempting to add text as a parameter and now get 0 as text :
```
function textNode(t)
    return "\\draw[xshift=50, yshift=50] node[draw, anchor=north west]{" .. t .. "};"
end
```
`\textNode{BBB}`


Do you know what should I do to get BBB.
Even `\textNode{"BBB"}` produces the same.

Comment: @FilippoGuenzi That seems like it's a separate question. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492630/passing-arguments-from-tex-to-a-lua-function to learn how to pass parameters to Lua functions.